# Regex with lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: php, regex, match

I have the following regexp that works great.

```
$str = "ID: {{item:id}} & First name: {{item:first_name}} & Page Title: {{page:title}}";

preg_match_all('/(?<={{)[^}]*(?=}})/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);

Returns:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => item:id
            [1] => item:first_name
            [2] => page:title
        )
)
```

How do I need to modify the regex to force it to match the item:id and item:first_name only (or any other string starting with "item:")? I tried adding the "item" to the regex (in several different places) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<={{)item:[^}]*(?=}})/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
Array
(
    [0] => item:id
    [1] => item:first_name
)
```

Comment: I actually tried (?<={{item:)[^}]*(?=}}).. Doh! Thanks for the correcy answer!

Answer (score 0):

With this you can group the tokens, so you don't need to limit the expression to any single type:

```
(?<={{)(.+?)(?:\:)(.+?)(?=}})
```

Example of utilization:

```
$str = "ID: {{item:id}} & First name: {{item:first_name}} & Page Title: {{page:title}}";

preg_match_all('/(?<={{)(.+?)(?:\:)(.+?)(?=}})/', $str, $matches);

$tokens = array();

foreach ($matches[0] as $i => $v) {
    $tokens[$matches[1][$i]][] = $matches[2][$i];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($tokens);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => id
            [1] => first_name
        )

    [page] => Array
        (
            [0] => title
        )

)
```

Comment: Pretty sweet! Thanks.